# Удаление массива через обвёртывание в String[] и удаления его уже через asList выдает ошибку

Tags: java, массивы, list, arraylist

Я знаю, что нельзя удалить данные из массива, но я попробовал **int[] ar** значения преобразовать в  **String[] arS**. После я создал **List list = new ArrayList**(Arrays.asList(arS)), для того чтобы можно было использовать метод **remove()**, для удаления значений из массива **String[] arS**, но проблема в том, что в **list**, данные удалились, а в самих массивах **arS и ar - нет**. Не подскажите пожалуйста, что в такой ситуации делать? Буду очень благодарен.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ar = {123, 234, 23, 4};
        String[] arS = new String[ar.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            arS[i] = Integer.toString(ar[i]);
        }
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arS));
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            list.remove(0);
        }
        System.out.println(list); // [], данные из массива удалились 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arS)); // [123, 234, 23, 4], а здесь данные
        //не удалились, хотя должны были, ведь это как, образно скажу, "Основной класс" 
        //(массив), а list, "дочерний класс" (массив).
        
        
        //List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arS));
        //list.remove(1);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));
    }
```

Comment: _проблема в том, что в list, данные удалились, а в самих массивах arS и ar - нет._  Проблема в том, что вы считаете это проблемой, так как вы _знаете_, что _нельзя_ удалить данные из массива.  После преобразования `ar -> arS`, из каждого примитивного числа создаётся _новый_ экземпляр/объект строки, который никоим образом не связан с числом в массиве `ar`.  Аналогично, после создания списка строк `list`, под капотом создаётся новый массив значений ссылок на строки, _не связанный_ с массивом `arrS`

Comment: _`// ...а здесь данные не удалились, хотя должны были,..`_ -- неверное предположение

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно, вы удаляете значения только из листа, массив к нему отношения никакого не имеет. Фактически вы просто скопировали значения из массива в лист при создании листа.
Если вы создали массив размером 4 элемента, он таким и останется (на 4 элемента). Для того чтобы получить массив с тремя элементами нужно либо создавать новый массив из 3 элементов, либо использовать динамический массив **ArrayList**

Пример кода с ArrayList ниже:

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
      List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
      list1.add(123);
      list1.add(234);
      list1.add(23);
      list1.add(4);

        System.out.println("Before remove:");
        System.out.println("list1"+list1+ "size: " + list1.size());
        System.out.println("list2"+list2+ "size:" + list2.size());
      list2.add(list1.remove(0));
      list2.add(list1.remove(0));
        System.out.println("After remove:");
      System.out.println("list1"+list1+ "size: " + list1.size());
      System.out.println("list2"+list2+ "size:" + list2.size());
    }
}
```

Выход

```
Before remove:
list1[123, 234, 23, 4]size: 4
list2[]size:0
After remove:
list1[23, 4]size: 2
list2[123, 234]size:2




Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужно для нормальной работы алгоритма, удаление из массива не нужных данных. Допустим у меня есть массив int[] a = {12, 23, 43, 122}, я достаю данные 12, 23 и сохраняю их в другой массив int[] b, а те данные которые были в массиве int[] a и были оттуда взяты, должны быть, оттуда удалены, то есть массив int[] a станет равный {43, 122}, а массив int[] b = {12, 23}.

Comment: В любом случае вам придется создавать новый массив. Либо вы это сделаете сами, либо вы используете ArrayList. (По сути произойдет тоже самое, но "за кулисами"). Пример с ArrayListom я добавил в ответ

Comment: Но разве это решает проблему удаления не нужных значений из массива? Массив в данной ситуации мне очень важен, а вот ArrayList не особо.

Comment: Если вам принципиально использовать массив, то вам при каждом удалении элемента из массива нужно будет создавать новый массив с размером меньше предыдущего на 1 элемент, потом копировать в новосозданный массив оставшиеся элементы из старого массива, и присваивать переменной ссылку на новый массив. ArrayList содержит "под капотом" обычный массив и удаление происходит по этой же логике

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понимаю зачем Вам такие "танцы с бубном"? int[] -> String[] -> List -> remove element -> int[]? Выглядит как бредятина какая-то...

Почему бы просто не написать свою функцию удаления элемента из массива массива или не использовать готовую библиотеку [Apache Common Lang 3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) и в ней `ArrayUtils.remove()`, например?

Пример такой функции ::

```
public static int[] remove(int[] array, int index) {
    final int length = array.length;
    if (index < 0 || index >= length) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: " + index + ", Length: " + length);
    }

    final int[] result = new int[length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, 0, index);
    if (index < length - 1) {
        System.arraycopy(array, index + 1, result, index, length - index - 1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Использование ::

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {123, 234, 23, 4};
    array = remove(array, 2);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // [123, 234, 4]
}
```